# Express status 404 with react-router and HTMLWebpackPlugin

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, react-router, html-webpack-plugin

My webpack config uses the HTMLWebpackPlugin that generates on the fly the index.html served.

```
plugins: [
  new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
    title: 'My App',
    favicon: path.join(__dirname, "../src/public/fav.ico")
  })
]
```

I'm exposing this generated index.html like this:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
```

I'm using, client-side, react-router, here are my routes:

```
export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="home" component={HomePage} />
  </Route>
)
```

Accessing http://localhost:1337/ works fine and display my "App" component properly, but when I try to access http://localhost:1337/home I get a 404 because its looks SERVER-SIDE for the route /home.

Of course if I add in my server.js:

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
  res.json({name: 'john'});
})
```

The call http://localhost:1337/home returns the proper json object.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score -1):

I usually am doing basic routes roughly like this:

```
let React = require('react');

let Router = require('react-router');
let DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute();
let Route = Router.Route();


<Route name="app" path="/" handler={require("./components/App"}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={require("./components/HomePage"} />
    <Route name="anotherSite" handler={require("./components/anotherSite"} />
    <Route name="about-us" handler={require("./components/About"} />
</Route>
```

you do not need to use a specific path, when naming the route. As a convention the route name equals the path except for when you intentionally create a path option with another path than the name.

If that does not help, please add further information to your question.

Comment: No, that's nothing to do with my issue unfortunately. My problem is that the browser tries to call the SERVER with the nested route (here /home) and of course does not find anything and get a 404.

Comment: i wanted to give you an alternative way of configuring routes. Usually express should have nothing to do with the app once the app finished loading. That is the weird part so I expect an error at the react part. The only thing you gave us are the routes. Because of that I asked for more information and tried to show a different routing approach in hope of fixing the problem